# Generating a Python script from within a Shell file

Tags: python, shell

Odd request, but I'd like to generate a Python file from within a shell file. So I read some parameters from a file and using those, I'd like to generate a full python script. Is there any easy way to do this or would I have to echo out things?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The question is very broad. What do you have in shell that you don't in python?

Comment: The use case I'm in, I've developed quite a bit in Shell and now this requirement has come up. Porting everything to Python is not very feasible at the moment.

Comment: In that case, what is there in Python that you don't have in shell?

Comment: Well. The Python generated script is required to be pushed elsewhere, not on the system I'm using Shell for. For if that was the case, like you said, I could've used Python rather than Shell.

Answer (score 0):

With `cat` you can do simple templates in shell:

```
NAME="George"
cat <<EOF | python 
print "Hello %s" % "$NAME"
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use placeholder values in your script and use sed to replace them

```
NAME="Fred"
sed "s/STRING_TO_REPLACE/$NAME/g" index.html
```

Or simply render a template completely from Python, you could take a look at Jinja2

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had a look at Jinja2, but it seems to be for the Django framework. I am trying to generate complete dynamic Python scripts.